# To define a color for every pallet type

Tags: anylogic

I have a database with my different pallet types which have an ID. Now I would like to assign to every ID a color. So for example at 10 am 54 pallets with the id 6 (blue) should be insert into my source block. So the only problem is to assign the colors to the ids. 
I have a 3D and a 2D simulation. I have my different color blocks and the ids but don't know what to do now.

[pallets_2dsimulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKcep.png)

[pallettype_2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j2kv.png)

[dbase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvyKr.png)

[dbase_pallet_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aPPZ.png)

[source_block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhXZV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have less than 140 ids, you can use this:

```
getStandardColor(id)
```

where id can be any integer from 0 to 139
otherwise use Benjamin's technique

if your object is 3D then you can use

```
object.setColor("Material__1__Surf", getStandardColor(id));
```

You can check the 3D object properties where "Material__1__Surf" is a possible identifier for the color of that part of the 3D object... 3D objects have generally more than only 1 color.

if it's a 2D object, these are generally composed by many different shapes... so you need to use getStandardColor(id) as the color in the shape in which that color is relevant.

Comment: First thank you. I attached 3 screenshots how I did it. How did the id know which color it is? Currently I have all colors in the process so 54 pallets with different colors

Comment: check the getStandardColor in the help documentation to discover its magic

Comment: yeah "Returns a standard color with the given index" , sry but don't know what I should do. I'm to unskilled in anylogic at the moment, because of that I often need the help of the sof community. problem is that I also don't find something about this things in the given books.

Comment: The best way is to have a tutor... Otherwise when you are doing projects that are too tough you will constantly run into blocks until you learn how to do things yourself... the books are not very useful as a reference for your custom models to be honest.

Comment: You're right. Could you please help me for this problem which I have to solve? If I have my different types my simulation will run perfectly so thats my last big problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a function "getMyColor" that takes an argument "id" (type int) and returns something of type "Color".

Inside the code, this will map i:

```
If(id>=0 && id <5) {
    return green;
}
else if...
```